# Programming ESP32 MCUs for production

Tags: nodemcu, esp32

Before committing to learning about the ESP32 and how to program it, I would like to know if the ESP can be programme the same way for production as it can on évaluation boards (with the Arduino IDE).

Since it obviusly much easier than most for microcontrollers, I was wondering if a product is eventually mass produced, if the code used to program the evaluation board (such as this one https://makeradvisor.com/tools/esp32-dev-board-wi-fi-bluetooth/) could be used on the final product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Most manufacturers would just require a binary (or HEX depending on MCU) file of your compiled code. If it's not a system they already know how to handle you will also need to provide a procedure for them to follow to program the device. What form that takes depends on the manufacturer.

You can also generally order pre-programmed MCUs and modules direct from the manufacturer where they (for a small fee) will program the chips for you before they are then sent to the board manufacturer for population.

If there is no facility on the MCU manufacturer's website then just email their sales department and I am sure they would be happy to quote you. Again, all they will require is a HEX or BIN file (depending on manufacturer) for programming.

Comment: Perfect Answer, thank you! To follow up, I'm assumant this means that using VSC, Atom, or the Arduino IDE, there is a procédure to build the code into a binary for the ESP32. Could you point me in the direction of such a procedure ? (research so far has gotten me to annexe articles such as 'how to make the binary smaller' etc...)\

Comment: Just compile your code as normal - then you just need to grab the binary from wherever it ends up (turn on verbose compiling to find where that is).